# Metapost label based on variable value

Tags: metapost

I want to label a scale based on a variable value and I wrote a metapost code like this.

```
$ := 1;
for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
    label.bot(str$,(i,-3.7cm));
    $ := incr($);
endfor;
```

It just labels "$" instead of its value. How to output the variables value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the value of the variable, use the `decimal` macro. The following works:

```
$:=1;
for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
    label.bot(decimal $,(i,-3.7cm));
    $ := incr($);
endfor
```

To quote the MetaPost manual:

> The `str` operator is generally for emergency use only.

further

> The `decimal` operator takes a number and returns the string representation.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with using solutions like

```
$ := 1;
for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
  label.bot(decimal $,(i,-3.7cm));
  $ := incr($);
endfor;
```

is that the `infont` operator is called to typeset the labels. `infont` has very few typesetting abilities, particularly with mathematical expressions, to the contrary of the `btex … etex` flags which allows the use of TeX and co. for this task.

Currently there are at least three ways to achieve the inclusion of variables in a label with MetaPost, while leaving the typesetting to (La)TeX:

- Using the `TEX.mp` package and the `TEX` function it defines.

  ```
  input TEX;
  beginfig(1);
  $ := 1;
  for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
    label.bot(TEX("$n_" & decimal $ & "$"),(i,-3.7cm));
    $ := incr($);
  endfor;
  endfig;
  end.
  ```

  `TEX.mp` calls Plain TeX by default to typeset the labels but it can be configured to use LaTeX as well. It works quite well, but processing a big loop takes an awful lot of time since each call of the `TEX` function triggers the creation and the processing of a new separate file. See [the MetaPost manual, p. 63 and 64](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) (as for the version contained in TeX Live 2014).
- Using the much more flexible `latexmp` package and its `textext` function, inspired from the function with the same name defined in the MetaFun format included in ConTeXt. This is by far the best way to include labels if you use standalone MetaPost and the LaTeX format for your papers. As its name implies, it uses LaTeX (exclusively) to typeset the labels. Contrary to TEX, it needs two runs to produce the labels (they can be automatized), but since these labels are passed to a single file for processing it goes much quicker anyway. Also `latexmp` is more easily configurable to suit the author's typesetting needs (e.g. for reproducing the LaTeX preamble of the file which is supposed to contain the drawings). The [`latexmp` documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/latexmp/doc/latexmp.pdf) is very well done and gives all the details.

  ```
   input latexmp;
   beginfig(1);
   $ := 1;
   for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
     label.bot(textext("$n_" & decimal $ & "$"),(i,-3.7cm));
     $ := incr($);
   endfor;
   endfig;
   end.
  ```
- Including the MetaPost program in a LuaLaTeX file (for example with the `standalone` class) and using the `luamplib` package. It also has a `textext` function with the same properties as before, but the author needs to run the file only once to produce the labels. See the [`luamplib` documentation](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf). The main advantage of this tactic is that the labels are automatically typeset in the same fonts as in the general LuaLaTeX document, and so it becomes possible to use OpenType fonts in MetaPost drawings (which is quite impossible to do with standalone MetaPost).

  ```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{luamplib}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
  beginfig(1);
  $ := 1;
  for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
   label.bot(textext("$n_" & decimal $ & "$"),(i,-3.7cm));
   $ := incr($);
  endfor;
  endfig;          
  \end{mplibcode}
  \end{document}
  ```

There is also the possibility to use ConTeXt and its own `textext` function, but I'm not fluent at all in this format.

Each of this method produces the same result, much more difficult to achieve with the mere use of strings combined with the `infont` operator (if it is possible at all to achieve it this way):

[image]

Comment: In ConTeXt MkIV, you don't need to use the `textext` function because all strings that are typeset using `infont` operator in metapost are typeset using TeX. So you can just use `label("$ n_{" & decimal(i) & "}$", origin)` and _it just works_

Comment: @Aditya Is it not because `textext` is still called, but behind the scene? And if I recall the Metafun manual correctly, `textext` must still be written explicitly in a standalone MetaPost file which uses ConTeXt as label typesetter and upon which you call the Metafun format. BTW, you can write only `label("the text", the_point)` with `latexmp` if you write `setupLaTeXmp(textextlabel=enable);` at the beginning of your `.mp` file. Same with LuaLaTeX and `luamplib` if you write `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` in the preamble. In both cases, `textext` will work but in the background.

Comment: @Aditya I've just searched the Metafun manual and as I recalled it is stated there (p. 42) that `textext` still does the work, but indeed in the background: "When you run inside ConTeXt (as we do here) there is no difference between `infont` and the TeX
methods. This is because we overload the `infont` operator and also pass its content to TeX. Both
`infont` and `btex` use the macro textext which is intercepted and redirects the task to TeX. This
happens in the current run so there is no need to pass extra information about fonts."

Answer (score 4):

If you need a label, which is in TeX (between btex and etex), and you want to use value of a variable there, you can do something like this:

```
a[0]:=1/2;
for t=0 upto 7:
  a[t+1]:=sqrt(a[t]);
  draw (a[t]*ux,a[t]*uy)--(a[t]*ux,a[t+1]*uy);
  draw (a[t]*ux,a[t+1]*uy)--(a[t+1]*ux,a[t+1]*uy);
  draw (a[t]*ux,-dx)--(a[t]*ux,dx);
  write "label.bot (btex $x_{"&decimal(t)&"}$ etex,(a["&decimal(t)&"]*ux,-dx));"
  to "mptextmp.mp";
endfor;

write EOF to "mptextmp.mp";
scantokens "input mptextmp"
```

See also this post on SO: [METAPOST: using loop variables in labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930810/metapost-using-loop-variables-in-labels)

Comment: The code I posted above was part of the metapost source used to obtain [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gLxsF.png).