# Fonts in math expressions in Metapost

Tags: fonts, metapost

I try to create a Metapost figure that contains math fonts, like:

```
beginfig(1); 

label.urt(btex $\mathfrak{b}$ etex,(100,0)); 

label(btex $\mathcal{X}_{\eta}$ etex,(-15,55)); 

endfig; 

end
```

Running "mpost filename" produces "Unable to make mpx file". The reason is the included fonts. What should I do to make it work?
Thanks,
Eilon

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34455/metapost-label-based-on-variable-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way: using the `latexmp` package and its `textext` macro. Contrary to the classical `btex…etex` flags, it allows you to use loops inside your labels.

```
input latexmp;
setupLaTeXMP(packages="amssymb");
beginfig(1); 
  label.urt(textext("$\mathfrak{b}$"),(100,0)); 
  for i = 1 upto 5:
    label(textext("$\mathcal{X}_{" & decimal i & "\eta}$"),(-15i,55)); 
  endfor
endfig; 
end.
```

[image]

The drawback is the fact you have to run the program twice to make the labels appear. To avoid that, you can set the package variable `mode` to `rerun`:

```
 setupLaTeXMP(packages="amssymb", mode=rerun);
```

with some restrictions which are detailed in the very well-made [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmp).

Comment: I probably do something completely wrong. I copy-paste the code you provided into the file figure.mp, and then I write in the command line "mpost figure". I keep on getting an error "Unable to make mpx file" with both codes you provided. What do I do wrong?

Comment: @Eilon What if you enforce the use of LaTeX as TeX typesetter? I.e. try `mpost --tex=latex figure.mp` (it shouldn't be necessary with `latexmp` nor with the classical `verbatimtex %&latex... etex` approach on most systems, but maybe your system is an exception.)

Comment: Many thanks, all! This works, with the only exception that I did not include the line "setupLaTeXMP(packages="amssymb");". When I included all math symbols appeared as the word "LaTeXMP" with a serial number...

Comment: @Eilon Yes, as I said, with LaTeXMP you have to run twice to make the labels appear, and you can automatize this double run by adding `mode=rerun` to the argument of `setupLaTeXMP`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
verbatimtex
%&latex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \begin{document}
etex;
prologues:=3;
beginfig(1);
label.urt(btex $\mathfrak{b}$ etex,(100,0));
label(btex $\mathcal{X}_{\eta}$ etex,(-15,55));
endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Many people write as
`verbatimtex`
`\end{document}`
`etex;`
when they choose latex in MetaPost.
However those lines are not needed
because intermediate TeX file for MetaPost always
ends with `\end{document}`, even in the case
of plain TeX.