# How to stringify numbers in Metapost?

Tags: metapost

I would like to label an axis like this:

[image: -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

Can I achieve this in a `for` loop without having to explicitly write all the commands separately like below?

```
label.top (btex $-3$ etex, (-3u, 0));
label.top (btex $-2$ etex, (-2u, 0));
label.top (btex $-1$ etex, (-1u, 0));
label.top (btex $0$ etex, (0u, 0));
label.top (btex $1$ etex, (1u, 0));
label.top (btex $2$ etex, (2u, 0));
label.top (btex $3$ etex, (3u, 0));
```

Comment: With Metafun you can do `for i = -3 upto 3: label.top ("$" & decimal i & "$", (i*u,0)); endfor` (No need for btex ... etex)

Comment: You can achieve this with the `latexmp` package. Or, if you use LuaLaTeX, with the luamplib package. See the answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34455/metapost-label-based-on-variable-value?noredirect=1&lq=1