# btex and etex in luamplib labels

Tags: luatex, metapost

I've been experimenting with `METAPOST` and in particular with `luamplib`. I found that I couldn't have `tex` typeset labels with the `btex`/`etex` construct as apparently is possible with straight up `METAPOST`.  After a little googling, I found that `btex`/`etex` can be made to work by using the files `luatexkomplib.tex` and the corresponding `luatexkomplib.lua` found [here](http://cvs.ktug.org/viewcvs/ko.TeX/luatexko/).  My usage is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\let\pdfescapename=\pdf@escapename
\let\pdfstrcmp=\pdf@strcmp
\input{luatexkomplib}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}

beginfig(1)
u=50;
draw fullcircle scaled u;
pickup pencircle scaled 2;
draw (u/2,0); draw(0,u/2); draw(-u/2,0); draw(0,-u/2);
label.rt(btex $\theta = 0$ etex scaled .5, (u/2,0));
label.top(btex $\theta = \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ etex scaled .5, (0,u/2));
label.lft(btex $\theta = \pi$ etex scaled .5, (-u/2,0));
label.bot(btex $\theta =\displaystyle{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$ etex scaled .5, (0,-u/2));
endfig;
end;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the expected circle with `tex` labelled points.  My question is: do I break anything by using these two files rather than using the `luamplib` package?  If not, then have I missed an updated `luamplib` package somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had I looked a little harder on Google, I would have found the following "TODO" page on the `luamplib` [GitHub](https://github.com/mpg/luamplib/blob/master/TODO):

> - use infwarerr and ltxcmds for Plain/LaTeX compat
> - use own verbatim env for LaTeX (à la luacode)
>     yep, will be much better than working arround fancyvrb
> - make variants of mplibcode with \ { } still special?
>
>   - actually, also make commands not changing the catcode as requested by
>       Arno T.
> - expand doc?
> - synchronize with Context?
> - add a figure with mpfun in the test files
>
> The following implement btex-etex commands:
>   http://cvs.ktug.or.kr/viewcvs/ko.TeX/luatexko/luatexkomplib.tex
>   http://cvs.ktug.or.kr/viewcvs/ko.TeX/luatexko/luatexkomplib.lua

Since these two files are mentioned as having implemented the `btex`/`etex` tags, I'll just assume that there is no problem with using them (and wonder why the package hasn't been updated to include them).

Answer (score 3):

Two years and a half later, and since Dohyun Kim (author of the `luatexkomplib` files) maintains `luamplib` himself, the situation has much evolved in this domain. In particular, since version 2.0 (2013/05) it supports the `btex…etex` flags directly. So the following code is sufficient to produce the required figure, in the document's current fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}

beginfig(1)
u=50;
draw fullcircle scaled u;
pickup pencircle scaled 2;
draw (u/2,0); draw(0,u/2); draw(-u/2,0); draw(0,-u/2);
label.rt(btex $\theta = 0$ etex scaled .5, (u/2,0));
label.top(btex $\theta = \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ etex scaled .5, (0,u/2));
label.lft(btex $\theta = \pi$ etex scaled .5, (-u/2,0));
label.bot(btex $\theta =\displaystyle{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$ etex scaled .5, (0,-u/2));
endfig;
end;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since version 2.03 (2013/12) `luamplib` even supports a `textext` macro similar to its ConTeXt's namesake. So the following code produces exactly the same output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}

beginfig(1)
u=50;
draw fullcircle scaled u;
pickup pencircle scaled 2;
draw (u/2,0); draw(0,u/2); draw(-u/2,0); draw(0,-u/2);
label.rt(textext("$\theta = 0$") scaled .5, (u/2,0));
label.top(textext("$\theta = \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{2}}$") scaled .5, (0,u/2));
label.lft(textext("$\theta = \pi$") scaled .5, (-u/2,0));
label.bot(textext("$\theta =\displaystyle{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$") scaled .5, (0,-u/2));
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The main advantage of `textext` (or its synonym `TEX`) is that it allows to handle variable in labels much more easily. For example, the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
      for i = 1 upto 5:
        label(textext("$n_" & decimal i & "$"), (i*cm, 0));
      endfor
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

Even handier, since version 2.6.0 (2014/03) if you insert `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` in preamble, each text of your labels (simply given as strings) will be typeset via `textext` automatically, and still in the document's current fonts. So the following code produces the same output as the one before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
      for i = 1 upto 5:
        label("$n_" & decimal i & "$", (i*cm, 0));
      endfor
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

See [`luamplib`'s documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf) for (much) more informations.