# Metapost crashes when adding tex labels

Tags: miktex, metapost

I am using Miktex 2.9 (64-bit) and TexnicCenter when compiling Metapost (version 1.504). My files will compile fine without labels. When I try to add a tex label, metapost crashes. I NEED HELP PLEASE!

Also, when compiling it is generating files with filenames like'mp755048' which have a .tex, .dvi, and .txt associated with the filename. The .dvi file contains the latex label by itself. The text file contains:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=tex 2012.3.18)  1 FEB   2013 16:44
**mp755048.tex
("C:\Users\Documents\Research\Thesis - Paper 2\Graphs\mp755048.tex"
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \documentclass
              {article}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \begin
      {document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1] [1] )
Output written on mp755048.dvi (2 pages, 340 bytes).
```

A minimal example that fails:

```
prologues :=3;
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
etex

beginfig(1);
    label(btex $x$ etex, origin);
endfig;
end;
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I get an error regarding the misplaced word "vertices" (that I believe should go before `etex`), but once corrected I have no problem.

Comment: I had a feeling my code would work for others. I think there is something wrong with the programs files. I have already re-installed Miktex. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you try making a really minimal example that fails? The shorter is the code, the easier is to find the problem.

Comment: Yes. Even this crashes: prologues :=3;
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
etex

beginfig(1);
        label(btex $x$ etex, origin);
endfig;
end;

Comment: Can you add the minimal example to your question, together with the .log file?

Comment: The example is added, but I cannot find the .log file. I don't think it generated.

Comment: Do you run Metapost on it? If you do, a log file *is* generated.

Comment: Yes. It seems to be generating these .tex files with filenames like mp755048. The .txt files are empty.

Comment: Sorry, let's hope that somebody expert with MiKTeX sees this; I'm on a different platform and both examples work for me.

Comment: It appears that metapost is running `tex` rather than `latex`. Try running `mpost -tex=latex filename`.

Comment: In TexnicCenter, I added mpost -tex=latex %tm.mp to the postprocessor Arguements when defining the output profile. Now, it generates an mpost.log.

Comment: @jonelle: and is the generated output correct?

Comment: No, it doesn't generate an image file.

Comment: A potential option: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82675/btex-and-etex-in-luamplib-labels

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. My initial workaround was to cut and paste mp code into Troy Henderson's MetaPost Previewer (http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/), which worked magnificently. Code that compiled and ran there would not run and generated the same error messages as above. 
Not happy with that situation, I found this link (https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/fr.comp.text.tex/ilcOWIxWcP4) which is in French but includes a Google translator if you are so inclined. I followed the 12 step procedure outlined, and while I was in the MikTeX Options (Admin) program on the Formats tab, I noticed the mptopdf key was excluded, so I re-enabled this. After updating formats, MetaPost ran without a hitch!
One problem relegated to the ash-heap of history.
Since I changed a few things simultaneously, I'm not sure which was the culprit. At this point, I'm just happy to have a working MP system.
Regards