# How to preview images generated by MetaPost?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, metapost, winedt

I use the old MetaPost program to create graphics.

My problem is that, to see the result of my MetaPost figures, I have to compile first the .mp file and then the .tex file where I've inserted them. I find it quite boring.

I've found the online [MetaPost Previewer](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/) but I have to copy and paste my code there and this is even a further waste of time.

I've also tried to add the lines

```
prologues:=3;
filenametemplate "%j-%3c.eps";
```

in my .mp files to generate .eps files, but, when I open them with GSView, sometimes I'm able to see my proper figures and sometimes not.

So, the question is: does anyone knows a program which is able to open the output generated by MetaPost? Or any package that can let me generate viewable images? Or any other trick that make me save some time (even an editor feature)?

If this can help, I use MiKTeX 2.9 in Windows XP. My main editor is TeXMaker (v4), but I have WinEdt (v8) installed as well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you setup GSview to clip pictures to the bounding box as described in section 14.2.1 in the [MetaPost manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution won't let you open your MetaPost images with a double-click of the mouse, but probably will let you save a lot of time.

Since you have WinEdt 8 installed, download the add-on [MetaPreview](http://www.winedt.org/macros/latex/MetaPreview.html) (choose the right version) and install it in WinEdt.

Note that the add-on provides a previewer for MetaPost output as well as one for MetaFont output. You can choose only the first one if you are not interested in MetaFont preview.

Once you've installed it, you will find a drop-down button in the toolbar which contains two buttons, as shown in the following image

[image]

To have these buttons enabled, you have to compile your `.mp` file first.

Once you've compiled your `.mp` file, with the first command ('MetaPost Preview All') you will be able to preview all the generated images, while with the other ('MetaPost Preview One') you will be prompted to choose the image you want to preview (useful when you're working on an image and want to preview only that one).

Just one remark: the add-on works regardless of the `prologue` but needs the generated output to be in the format `.1`, `.2`, etc., so delete the line

```
filenametemplate "%j-%3c.eps";
```

from your `.mp` files.

---

### UPDATE

A new version of [MetaPreview](http://www.winedt.org/macros/latex/MetaPreview.html) is available.

The limitation described above has been overcome. Now it can be used even when your `.mp` file contains

```
filenametemplate "%j-%c.mps";
```

or

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try the add-on you've mentioned.

Comment: I have to thank you very much. I've tried MPPreview as you suggested and it is just the tool I was looking for! Just have to click a button to preview my images in my favourite PDF viewer is awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: The `filenametemplate` primitive is deprecated since MetaPost version 1.200.  It has been replaced by a new internal variable `outputtemplate`.  Please update your MetaPost distribution.

Answer (score 8):

If you're not opposed to compiling with `lualatex`, then you could make use of the [`luamplib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib) package to bypass the preview step altogether and compile the images in-document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
Your usual document.
\begin{mplibcode}

%your metapost code here

\end{mplibcode}
The rest of your document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `luamplib` support TeX labels?

Comment: @aditya It does now it seems.  The patch pointed out [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/opentype-fonts-for-metapost-labels#comment253104_28548) seems to have been implemented if the documentation is to be believed.  The github listed as the homepage may no longer be where the actual package code resides.

Comment: Scott, @Aditya: The patch is in the CTAN version of luamplib, but I think it can't yet be in Texlive or Miktex.

Comment: @charlesstewart. Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  Do you have an idea of how long it might take?

Comment: @ScottH. I tried the new `luamplib` in CTAN with TeX Live 2013/pretest and it seems to work with labels. We have only to wait for the release and the package will be updated soon.

Answer (score 8):

If you have ConTeXt standalone installed, then you can just run:

```
context filename.mp
```

which will generate `filename.pdf`.

Answer (score 6):

The [MetaPost manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) describes various ways for previewing MetaPost graphics.  To quote from a section titled *Previewing PostScript Output:*

> Previewing MetaPost’s PostScript output is not difficult, but there are some catches that one should know about. This section deals with the following questions: How can graphics be clipped to their true bounding box in the PostScript viewer application? Why are my text labels rendered with an ugly font (or not at all) and how to avoid that? How can several graphics be combined into a multi-page document that can be previewed within one instance of the viewer application?

It then discusses these tools

- GSview
- mproof.tex
- mpsproof.tex

and mentions

- mptopdf
- mpstoeps.pl
- [Troy's MetaPost online compiler](http://tlhiv.org/mppreview/)

as additional alternatives.

*Side note: I happen to have written the work-flow and preview related stuff in the MetaPost manual.  If you think there's anything missing or unclear and could be improved, please drop me a line.*

Comment: Finally I'm able to see my MetaPost graphics in GSView! I did it by activating 'EPS Clip' in Options. Thanks! However I prefer to see them in my PDF viewer thanks to karlkoeller's suggestion.

Comment: That is really easy with the mpsproof.tex script, which is part of the MetaPost distribution.  Use it like `pdftex mpsproof *.mps` after setting the file extension of MetaPost output to `mps` by putting the line `outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps";` in the preamble of the source file.

Comment: @StephanHennig So you are involved in MetaPost development. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and the MetaPost version that is shipped with it is still 1.504... This version does not even contain `mpsproof.tex` and most of the things you've written in this post are not even contemplated in the 1.504 manual. Any chance you convince C.Schenk to update MetaPost in MiKTeX distribution?

Comment: The MetaPost binary in MiKTeX 2.9 Portable seems to be of version 1.504, which is OK, but the manal is of version 1.005.  Please complain to the distributor.  The `mpsproof.tex` script has been added to the MetaPost distribution in version 1.100.  You can find it at [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/base/texmf/tex/generic/metapost/mpsproof.tex).

Comment: Or try another TeX distribution.  TeX Live works well on Windows.

Comment: @StephanHennig Write my name preceeded by `@` to answer to me here otherwise I won't be notified... Anyway, have a look [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2199/)

Comment: @karlkoeller That bug report is about updating MetaPost. But MiKTeX's MetaPost seems to be completely broken (inconsistent and incomplete). Is Christian Schenk aware of that? I rember a similar situation a few year ago, which made me switch to TeX Live. Seeing this mess still, I can only recommend MetaPost users not to use MiKTeX (sorry).

Comment: @karlkoeller  BTW, TL2012 contains a complete MetaPost 1.504 and TL2013 (in pretest) contains a complete MetaPost 1.802. Latest manual still claims to be for v1.504, but that's because it hasn't been updated to reflect the changes since then. Which is unfortunate, too. `:(` Latest changes are described in the `CHANGES` file.

Comment: @StephanHennig I'm not aware of all broken things in MiKTeX MetaPost, but you are. So: 1. you can point them out to C.Schenk (as a MetaPost developer, you have a chance to be listened). 2. you can tell them to me and I will post a bug report (not the best solution, since I don't have your reputation with MetaPost).

Comment: @StephanHennig Probably the best way to convince C.Schenk to update MetaPost is that the latest version is loaded to CTAN. Do you think this is doable?

Comment: @karlkoeller I've just checked back with the main developers (which I'm not).  Either version, 1.212 or 1.504, would be OK to update to.  Taco plans to release a new version 1.803 in 'a few weeks,' which will make it to CTAN again.  (In the meantime, MiKTeX should _consolidate_ MetaPost to either a complete version 1.212 or version 1.504.  The 1.5 series contains many internal changes, but adds no new user-visible features, except some fixed bugs.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gmp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}
%beginfig(1};
a=3cm; b=2cm;
z0=(0,0);
z1=-z3=(a,0);
z2=-z4=(0,b);
draw z1..z2..z3..z4..cycle;
draw z1--z0--z2;
label.top(btex $a$ etex, .5[z0,z1]);
label.lft(btex $b$ etex, .5[z0,z2]);
dotlabel.bot(btex $(0,0)$ etex, z0);
%endfig;
\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

Just comment out the `beginfig` and `endfig` lines and compile with the `-shell-escape` option active.