# Code to preview metapost output?

Tags: metapost

Does anyone out there have a cute way of previewing images generated by MetaPost? As far as I can tell, after making the .mp file there is a bit a process for viewing the file. I figure there aught to be an easy script to write that would convert the .mp file to a .pdf, and then open the .pdf with Adobe, or something along those lines, but I lack the ability to write BASH code, or even know the proper terminology to use to talk about such scripts. (BASH code, shell scripts... Something)

Edit: I forgot to mention, I was looking for such a script that would run *automatically* after compiling in TexMaker. Again, I assume there must be a way to do such a thing, but I don't know how. I want to be able to click the "MPost" build option, and then see a preview, without needing to go through the trouble manually running the conversion command.

Comment: You mean, like `mptopdf`? Note that one complication is that there need not be a one-to-one mapping from `.mp` to `.pdf`, so the situation is rather unlike the usual `.tex` case. (There need not be such a mapping there either but there usually is. That's not so for an `.mp` file.)

Comment: Try the `\convertMPtoPDF` command...

Comment: @Malipivo Is that a command in the document, or in the command line? I found the command that converts them, but I want something that will open up the document as soon as I build it in TexMaker- looking at my post I see I omitted that. Let me append to my question.

Comment: If you are on Mac OS X, there are the very handy Perl scripts of Nicola Vitacolonna (based on `mptopdf`, but much more friendly) for previewing MetaPost programs: https://users.dimi.uniud.it/~nicola.vitacolonna/home/software/metapost-texshop/. They were devised for TeXShop, but they can be run from any Unix command line, and so they should be compatible with any editor which can launch external tasks. I don't know about their compatibility with Windows.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, should it still work?

Comment: @Anthony I think so, it's also a Unix. But don't take my word on it, since I don't know anything more about Ubuntu. Better give it a try (don't forget to read the very well-made documentation carefully) and in case of problems you may contact Nicola Vitacolonna directly.

Comment: I've forgotten, there is also the possibility of including the MetaPost code into a LuaLaTeX program, thanks to the `luamplib` package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib. In combination with the `standalone` class, it produces ready-to-use PDF outputs. I've often used it this way myself on this site, for example here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234116/how-to-fill-an-area-below-sine-wave/234158#234158

Comment: I've asked the same question time ago. Probably one of the answers there might be of help. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118208/31910.

Comment: You can use `arara` or something to convert them and maybe even to open the results. (Or you can configure your editor to open the results.) But the question remains: which PDF should be opened? All of them? Some of them?

Comment: On OSX, Skim.app does on-the-fly conversion to PDF with live updating - the trick is to use `prologues:=3` and an `outputtemplate` with an extension of `.eps`.  If you open the `.eps` file in Skim, and turn on the "check for file changes" option (on the Sync tab), it will automagically update the PDF copy when the `.eps` changes.

Comment: @cfr Nicola Vitacolonna's scripts (`nv-metapost` and `nv-metafun`) don't choose: they both create a PDF file that includes all the figures defined in the MetaPost file (each figure having its own page), and they both open this multiple-paged PDF for viewing.

Comment: @fpast Good to know. But what I meant was: this is something you have to decide. You can create a one-many-one mapping, but that is a decision and might or might not be what you want. (In my case, it would not typically be at all what I wanted!)